# System.exit(0) reached before maximum user attempts made reached

Tags: java

I may have confused my self with the logic for some time now and I could use some assistance. So I have created this function to return a Voucher # (size is 4-digits). The pre-condition is two characters entered must be correct and in their respective placing below the application reveals the rest of the Voucher digits (when compared with voucher in record).

I am giving the user 3 attempts to search the voucher with the only two known voucher digits. After three attempts and if the voucher does not exist. I'll lock the user and close the app with System.exit(0).

However, System.exit(0) executes when attempt = 3. It seems I don't have control over my loop.

```
int attempts = 3;

while (attempts != 0){

 if(VoucherNumber.charAt(0) == VoucherRecord.charAt(0) &&
           VoucherNumber.charAt(1) == VoucherRecord.charAt(1))

           System.out.println("Reveal all digits");

         }

        else if(VoucherNumber.charAt(0) == VoucherRecord.charAt(0) &&
                VoucherNumber.charAt(2) == VoucherRecord.charAt(2) ){

                System.out.println("Reveal all digits");

        }

        else{

               System.out.println("Reveal all digits");

               attempts--;   


               if (attempts == 0){

                    System.exit(0);
               }                                        
        }
```

Comment: subtract from `attempts` after you've checked it for the round...

Comment: Yes, I put that in the last 
"else" block

Comment: Yes, before you checked it's value... `if (attempts == 0){

                    System.exit(0);
               }attempts--;`

Comment: @xs0, The input should be the number of times the mouse is clicked.

Comment: VoucherNumber never changes.. it must change, if you want 3 attempts, now you're doing just 1 attempt several times..

Comment: @xs0, thanks, running it now.

Comment: Still the same. I guess I use a OnClickListener plus added conditions. But thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You should get new input from user inside the while loop. As it is, you seem to get the input once, then run the loop 3 times with the same input..